Convert output of turfjs turf.lineChunk to turf.points
Just wondering if there is a way to easily convert the output of turf.lineChunk to turf.points?
     testLineString = {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {},
        "geometry": {
            "type": "LineString",
            "coordinates": [                    
                [
                    155.9668,
                    -2.9402
                ],
                [
                    162.959225,
                    -2.94504
                ],
            ]
        }                   
    };

var chunk = turf.lineChunk(testLineString, 25, { units: "kilometers" });

var points = turf.points([ [], [], [], ]);

Hoping for something simple like this (but this doesn't work)
var points = turf.points(chunk.features); 

I would like the points to be able to be used in turf.pointsWithinPolygon()
var inside = turf.pointsWithinPolygon(points ,turfpolygon);

Thank you.

Does not seem to be an easy way to do this other than a loop like below:
for (var x = 0; x < chunkedLine.features.length; x++) {
  if (foundWithinPolygon == false) {
                                    points = turf.points([
                                        [chunkedLine.features[x].geometry.coordinates[0][0], chunkedLine.features[x].geometry.coordinates[0][1]],
                                        [chunkedLine.features[x].geometry.coordinates[1][0], chunkedLine.features[x].geometry.coordinates[1][1]],
                                    ]);
                                    var ptsWithin = turf.pointsWithinPolygon(points, turfpolygon);
                                    if (ptsWithin.features.length > 0) {
                                        foundWithinPolygon = true;
                                        break;
                                    }
                    }
    }

